# Distribution of sums and differences of n correlated normal random variables

Tags: self-study, correlation, normal-distribution, random-variable, covariance

Suppose $x_1\sim\mathcal N(2,0.5),x_2\sim \mathcal N(2,3),$ and $x_3\sim \mathcal N(2.5,7)$ with correlations $\rho_{(1,2)}=0.3,\rho_{(1,3)}=0.1,$and $\rho_{(2,3)}=0.4.$ What is the distribution  of

1. $x_1+x_2+x_3?$
2. $x_1+ (3\times x_2)+x_3?$
3. $x_1+x_2+(0.5\times x_3)?$

   Solutions:
4. The distribution of $x_1+x_2+x_3 =\mathcal{N}(6.5,15.275)$.
5. The distribution of $x_1+(3\times x_2)+x_3=\mathcal{N}(10.5,30.077)$
6. The distribution of $x_1+x_2+(0.5\times x_3)=\mathcal{N}(5.25,8.005)$

   But I want to know what is the distribution of $(2\times x_1)-(3\times x_2)-x_3$ and $x_1+x_2-(2\times x_3)?$

   The distribution of $(2\times x_1)-(3\times x_2)-x_3$ is $\mathcal{N}(-4.5,41.8407).$

The distribution of $x_1 +x_2-(2\times x_3) $ is $\mathcal{N}(-1,24.1544)$

Comment: Are they jointly normal?

Comment: @gunes, They are jointly normal in the sense that if $x_1=1$, then $x_2=-0.4494897447$ and $x_3=-1.24165.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're assumed to be *jointly normal*, a situation which normally should be given to you, we already know that any linear combination of jointly normal RVs is a univariate normal. In that case, we only need to figure out the mean and variance. Your answer for (1) is therefore correct. For the other options you'll apply the following formulas:

$$E[aX+bY+cZ]=a\mu_x+b\mu_y+c\mu_z$$
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{var}(aX+bY+cZ) &=a^2\sigma_x^2+b^2\sigma_y^2+c^2\sigma_z^2+2(ab\rho_{xy}\sigma_x\sigma_y+ac\rho_{xz}\sigma_x\sigma_z+bc\rho_{yz}\sigma_y\sigma_z)\end{align}$$
In (1), you implemented and obtained this for $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: I think the expression for the variance is not correct. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution and https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat505/lesson/4/4.2 or wolfram for examples. The term with the correlation coefficients has a negative sign, not a positive sign.

Comment: If we decrease it to two variables, we should have $$\operatorname{var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{cov}(X+Y, X+Y)=\operatorname{var}(X)+2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)+\operatorname{var}(Y)$$ Therefore, it should be correct.

Comment: Yes it is correct. I was confusing joint distribution with sums or differences! Thank you